# retaining quotes in bash correctly

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I am trying to pass arguments from a bash script to an executable and one of them contains spaces. I have been searching how to solve this, but I cannot find the  right way to do it. Minimal example with a script called `first` and a script called `second`.

first script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# first script
ARGS="$@"
./second $ARGS
```

second script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# second script
echo "got $# arguments"
```

Now if I run it like this, I get the following results:

```
$ ./first abc def
got 2 args
$ ./first "abc def"
got 2 args
$ ./first 'abc def'
got 2 args
```

How can I make it so, that the second script also only receives one argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't do it using an intermediate variable. If you quote it will always pass 1 argument, if you don't you will lose the quotes.

However, you can pass the arguments directly if you don't use the variable like this:

```
./second "$@"
```

```
$ ./first abc def
got 2 arguments
$ ./first "abc def"
got 1 arguments
```

Alternately, you can use an array to store the arguments like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
# first script
ARGS=("$@")
./second "${ARGS[@]}"
```

Comment: Okay, given this limitation, how can I parse/check the args in the first script? I am using shift to check for some values and only if they exists, I run the second script.

Comment: @André Then you can use the array to store the values. The values in the array will stay intact even after you call shift

Comment: I was not clear enough, there are other parameters as well, but this way it will all end up being one parameter. What I actually have is something like ./first "foo bar" something "something else"

Comment: @André Hmmm. It says `got 3 arguments` with these arguments (at least on my pc). What do you get?

Comment: I had a typo, it actually works. Thanks, you are my hero of the day!

Answer (score 0):

IFS is your friend .

```
#!/bin/bash
# first script
ARGS="$@"
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
./second $ARGS
```

IFS stands for Internal Field Separator ...

Comment: With bash, you can use [ANSI-C quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#ANSI_002dC-Quoting): `IFS=$'\n\b'`